# Executable jar can't locate packaged resources

Tags: java, maven

I have the following piece of code to read file from resources:

```
randomFirstName = rReader.generate(
new FileReader(classLoader.getResource("NamesFem.txt").getFile()));
```

It works fine when I run it from IDEA.

I need to put the project into executable jar with maven. That's my `pom.xml` config for assembly plugin:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>com.myPackage.CreateXlsFile</mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

When I try to run packed jar, I get the following exception: `Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/Users/myUser/MyProject/target/my-project-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/NamesFem.txt (No such file or directory)`

When I manually unpack the jar all the files are there in the root dir of jar:

[image]

What's wrong?

Comment: Just use API that is based on `InputStream`. eg `new InputStreamReader(classLoader.getResource("NamesFem.txt").openStream()));`

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing the issue is that the `URL.getFile` method doesn't work on JAR file contents.  When trying to read something explicitly from a JAR file, I've always used `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream` instead.  Something like:

```
randomFirstName = rReader.generate(
    new InputStreamReader(
      classLoader.getResourceAsStream("NamesFem.txt")
    )
);
```

This *should* work whether `NamesFem.txt` is in your JAR file or in your classpath as a separate file, i.e. in your IDE environment.